# Upgrade from PHP 5.3.2 to PHP 5.3.10?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, vps, linode

I have a VPS account from Linode.

I've installed Ubuntu 10.04 LTS with 'LAMP Stack' (StackScript).

How to upgrade the latest version of PHP version 5.3.10 from PHP 5.3.2?

I have even tried apt-get and it doesn't update.

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/369399/how-to-install-a-newer-version-of-php-as-a-package/369400#369400

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`apt` can't upgrade what it didn't install.  You would run into the same problem if you downloaded PHP directly from php.net and compiled it yourself... `apt` still wouldn't upgrade it for you.

You can either use the upgrade path that Linode StackScripts provide.  (I wasn't able to find one by browsing their website.) or you can uninstall the StackScripts version of PHP and use `apt` to install the one you want.

I have no idea how StackScripts will handle not being in control of PHP.  You may want to uninstall StackScripts entirely and install Apache, MySQL and PHP through `apt` instead.

If you have more Linode-specific questions, you may find more expertise over in their [forums](http://forum.linode.com/viewforum.php?f=10) or [IRC channel](http://www.linode.com/irc/).

Comment: StackScripts is a batch script, it use `apt` to download PHP, Apache and MySQL.

Comment: In that case, have a look in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.  It may be that the repositories you are using don't have anything more recent than PHP 5.3.2.

Comment: ubuntu repository doesn't have the latest version of PHP. so I might have to download from PHP.net